# Retina display vs regular

Tags: iphone

Apple wants me to fix my interface with retina display/regular display. With the same picture 320x480 the picture looks the same on iOS simulator for both retina and regular as background. But when I do 960x640 for retina and 320x480 for regular, retina  looks lilke it is all zoomed in. What am I missing here lol. Is it because it is background layer?

Comment: what pictures? resources? or from the photo library or camera? be more specific, please.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is the problem exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: My app got rejected due to retina display issues 10.6 not fitting resolution, so I am trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a UIImageView for your background then you probably need to change the contentMode setting to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill so that the image is properly scaled inside the bounds of the UIImageView.

Comment: does cocos2d engine autosize for you?